# Perl is polymorphism worth it?

Tags: perl, oop, polymorphism

There seem to be a number of ways to do polymorphism in Perl but they all feel "hacky" to me. I'm somewhat new to Perl so I could just be interpreting it wrong but I find most examples make your code too illegible and are controversial.

Say you have a widget class that contains some data and methods that all widgets need. There are also a handful of widget types (i.e. calender, schedule, etc). And they need to communicate with each other (via a parent container class).

Would playing with the namespace and making widget a prototype be worth it?
Should I give each widget a reference to an object (one of the types) at instantiation?
Just forget about types being objects and make widget a large class where only a few methods get used per instance based on what type is set.
Something else?

I come from a C/C++ background and I'm finding it difficult to decide on a Perl programming model.

Also, I'm don't have strong type safety or private member requirements. The project is a mid sized web app with a couple developers and portability to other projects isn't a priority. Easy extensibilty without needing to decipher Perl hacks would be useful though.

Comment: What do you mean by a "prototype"? Have you checked `Moose`?

Comment: The standard way to call of calling methods (`$o->method()`) has them behave as virtual methods. Polymorphism is free. What hacks are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not a big believer of Perl OOP, it exists, it's functional, but it's not what Perl is for. It's like using a screwdriver as a hammer. It's a shell scripting language, that can be used for general purpose scripting. I'm surprised you're doing a new(?) web app in Perl.

Comment: @EugeneK, nonsense! Since the advent of Moose, Perl has had an OO framework which leaves every other mainstream programming language standing in the dust.

Comment: @EugeneK, Perl OO may seem a litle clumiser than a pure OO language like Java, but it has a definite place within the language.  "A shell scripting language" is also a short-sell, in my opinion.  Consider DBI alone, Win32::OLE or Excel::Writer::XLSX, and imagine them without OO capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Modern Perl" approach is probably to define `Widget` as a role. A role can be thought of as similar to a mixin, an interface, or an abstract base class. Do this with [Moose::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose%3a%3aRole) or one of its more light-weight alternatives ([Moo::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo%3a%3aRole), [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role%3a%3aTiny)).

```
{
   package Widget;
   use Moo::Role;

   sub some_common_method {
      my $self = shift;
      ...;
   }

   sub another_common_method {
      my $self = shift;
      ...;
   }

   # Here we're indicating that all Widgets must
   # have a method called yet_another_common_method,
   # but we're not defining how that method should
   # be implemented.
   requires "yet_another_common_method";
}
```

Now you can create a class that composes that role:

```
{
   package Calendar;
   use Moo;
   with "Widget";

   # Here's a member variable.
   has year => (is => "ro", required => 1);

   # Widget requires us to implement this.
   sub yet_another_common_method {
      my $self = shift;
      ...;
   }

   # We can override Widget's implementation
   # of this method.
   sub some_common_method {
      my $self = shift;
      ...;
   }

   # We can install hooks ("method modifiers")
   # to Widget's methods.
   before another_common_method => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      print STDERR "Calendar ", $self->year, ": another_common_method() was called.\n";
   };
}
```

And another:

```
{
   package Schedule;
   use Moo;
   with "Widget", "Editable";

   sub yet_another_common_method {
      my $self = shift;
      ...;
   }
}
```

And use the classes:

```
my $calendar = Calendar->new( year => 2014 );
my $schedule = Schedule->new;

my @widgets = ($calendar, $schedule);

for (@widgets) {
   $_->some_common_method if $_->does('Widget');
}
```

Comment: Hey, I notice you are enclosing your packages in `{}`. Does this do something I should know about?

Comment: If you define multiple packages in the same file, it can be useful to prevent, e.g. lexical variables leaking from one package into another. Now sometimes (rarely) you'll actually *want* there to be a lexical variable that is accessible across all the packages defined in a file, in which case you'd define that variable outside all the `{ }` bits. Which means that it will stand out visually, which seems to be a good thing for such a variable! Of course, in most cases people define one package per file making this a moot point.